# How to connect postgres database with logstash from JDBC to import data?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm trying to connect `PostgreSQL` database with `Logstash` to import data from `postgres` to `elasticsearch`.
I'm using JDBC driver to connect `Logstash` with `postgres`.

But i'm getting following error

> [2019-06-27T13:04:05,943][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin
>   had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
>   Pipeline_id:main   Plugin: "postgres", jdbc_password=>, statement=>"SELECT 
>   * FROM public.\"contacts\";", jdbc_driver_library=>"postgresql-42.2.6.jar",
>   jdbc_connection_string=>"jd
>   bc:postgresql://localhost:5432/LogstashTest",
>   id=>"a76a604bb9cb591dd4a19afc95e03873023e008c564101b4ac19aefe30071213",
>   jdbc_driver_class=>"org.postgresql.Driver", enable_metric=>true,
>   codec=>"plain_8f80bf3a-29fe-49e8-86b1-c94e9a298ffb", enable_metric=>true,
>   charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000,
>   jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=
>
> > 3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1,
> >     connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5,
> >     parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC},
> >     last_run_metadata_path=>"C :\Users\roshan/.logstash_jdbc_last_run",
> >     use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric",
> >     clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
> >     Error: org.postgresql.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included
> >     the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?   Exception:
> >     LogStash::ConfigurationError   Stack:
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:163:in
> >     `open_jdbc_connection'
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:221:in`
> >     execute_statement'
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:277:in `execute_query'
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:263:in`run'
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:309:in
> >     `inputworker'
> >     D:/Swares/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:302:in`
> >     block in start_input'
> >     [2019-06-27T13:04:06,946][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Failed to
> >     load postgresql-42.2.6.jar {:exception=>#}

My configurations are

- Java version  - "1.8.0_211"
- postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.0
- logstash-7.2.0

And here is my logstash conf file

```
input {
    jdbc{
        #input configuration
        jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-42.2.6.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/LogstashTest"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        statement => 'SELECT  * FROM public."contacts";'
    }
}
output{
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Comment: _"Failed to load postgresql-42.2.6.jar"_, it sounds like either `postgresql-42.2.6.jar` is missing, or it isn't in the location expected by logstash.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no i have put it in bin

Comment: Thanks for asking. I had an issue as was not using `""` for username and password.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can occur due to corrupted PostgreSQL JDBC driver when you passing incorrect config file to Logstash. I had the same issue, you need to check your JDBC driver file.